# Swift - How to jump to the top using becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Here's what I want to do , when I click on my `button` I want to jump the top but when I click on the `button` my app crashes.

```
@IBAction func addToCart(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if quantitylbl.text == "0" {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    // Save in to userdefault
    let section = sender.tag / 100
    let row = sender.tag % 100
    let dict = arrayCategory[section] as? NSDictionary
    let subLimit = getStringValueFromAPIValue(apiValue: dict?.value(forKey: "limit"), defaultValue: "")

    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as! CustomizationDropDownTableViewCell

    if self.section_quantity[section] < Int(truncating: subLimit.numberValue!) {
        cell.btnDropdown.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to safely unwrap the cell.

Comment: it's not working @SavcaMarin

Comment: It's not fixing the crash or it's not moving you to top?

Comment: it's not moving to the top when i scroll to the bottom.

Comment: What line is crashing? Give some more details. Also I'm almost sure you must scroll to the cell first `tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)`, and only after that you'll have the cell and all it's UI components loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
let subLimit = getStringValueFromAPIValue(apiValue: dict?.value(forKey: "limit"), defaultValue: "")
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as! CustomizationDropDownTableViewCell
```

I'm not sure what exact problem makes your App crash. Try to make some breakpoints in your code. I think there might be a problem with the optional issues.

The subLimit is optional, so make sure it has a value when forced unwrapping. Int(truncating: subLimit.numberValue!)

Also, use the forced form of the type cast operator (as!) only when you are sure that the downcast will always succeed. 
See Apple's Swift document. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html